# Spring Cloud Kubernetes get url with custom spring.servlet.context-path

Tags: openshift, spring-boot-admin, spring-cloud-kubernetes

We are currently using Spring Boot Admin for monitoring our microservices inside the OpenShift cluster.
Spring Boot Admin aplication get information about services from the Openshift's Service Discovery using *spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes* dependency.

Everything was fine until we deployed application with custom *server.servlet.context-path*.

For example, our microservice has *server.servlet.context-path=/dictionary*. However, Spring Boot Admin get the following information from the OpenShift's discovery:

```
{
    "registration": {
        "name": "dictionary-service",
        "managementUrl": "http://10.130.1.169:8080/actuator",
        "healthUrl": "http://10.130.1.169:8080/actuator/health",
        "serviceUrl": "http://10.130.1.169:8080/",
        "source": "discovery",
        "metadata": {
            "app": "dictionary-service",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

So, Spring Boot Admin is expecting actuator working on `"http://10.130.1.169:8080/actuator"` but it's actually working on `"http://10.130.1.169:8080/dictionary/actuator"`

How can we customize *managementUrl* and *healthUrl* so our Spring Boot Admin server could use correct URL for monitoring this service?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. But resolved with an other solution:

1. I change the management port on my Spring Boot Application

```
management.server.port=8090
server.port=8080
```

Now the management end-points (/actuator, /actuator/health) aren't effected by "server.servlet.context-path".

2. I opened the ports on my k8s deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: ${docker_image}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        - containerPort: 8090
```

3. I declared the ports with a name on my k8s service

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: app
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    name: api
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8090
    targetPort: 8090
    name: management
```

4. I said to Spring Boot Admin witch port name to use

```
spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.primary-port-name=management
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is supported out-of-the-box if you add a "management.context-path" annotation to the Service metadata, e.g.:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: carts
  annotations:
    management.context-path: /carts/actuator
```

The Spring Boot Admin [DefaultServiceInstanceConverter](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/blob/master/spring-boot-admin-server-cloud/src/main/java/de/codecentric/boot/admin/server/cloud/discovery/DefaultServiceInstanceConverter.java) will automatically read from the Spring Cloud Discovery metadata and look for this to set up the proper management & health paths.
For it to work you need to have the property `spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.metadata.add-annotations` set to true (which is the [default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/appendix.html) anyways)

P.S.: I don't have an OpenShift cluster to test with but it worked for me locally with minikube and on an Amazon EKS cluster.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I finally solved it. Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

**"registration"** object from the question is generated in Spring Boot Admin itself. It's the reliability of the *ServiceInstanceConverter* interface. By default, *DefaultServiceInstanceConverter* implementation is used (you can read more about this [here](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#_converting_serviceinstances)).

There are several metadata keys that can be used to modify your *managementUrl* and *healthUrl* (by default, *"/actuator"* and *"/actuator/health"* are used respectively).

First, I thought we can use *management.context-path* metadata key to append our *server.servlet.context-path*, but unfortunately, you can't use "/" character in metadata label value ("dictionary/actuator" is invalid), so it wasn't enough in my case.

Instead, we decided to extend *DefaultServiceInstanceConverter* and override *convert* and *getManagementPath* methods:

```java
@Component
public class OpenShiftServiceInstanceConverter extends DefaultServiceInstanceConverter {

    private static final String MANAGEMENT_CONTEXT_PATH = "/actuator";
    private static final String MANAGEMENT_PREFIX = "management.prefix";

    @Override
    public Registration convert(ServiceInstance instance) {
        return Registration.create(instance.getServiceId(), getHealthUrl(instance).toString())
                .managementUrl(getManagementUrl(instance).toString()).serviceUrl(getServiceUrl(instance).toString())
                .metadata(getMetadata(instance)).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getManagementPath(ServiceInstance instance) {
        String managementPath = instance.getMetadata().get(MANAGEMENT_PREFIX);
        if (!isEmpty(managementPath)) {
            return managementPath + MANAGEMENT_CONTEXT_PATH;
        }
        return MANAGEMENT_CONTEXT_PATH;
    }
}
```

This way, we can just include *server.servlet.context-path* as metadata *management.prefix* key in service template:

```yaml
kind: Template
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dictionary-service
annotations:
  description: Template for Dictionary Service 1.0.0
labels:
  app: dictionary-service
  management.prefix: dictionary
...
```

And now it is working like a charm.